# String - Search Index of All Specified Strings

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String for example

```
String value1 = "12345 abc 123 def 123";
```

and another one to be searched on it

```
String value2 ="123";
```

for example.

How can I return all the indices the 2nd string appears on the first? From what I've searched, `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` searches the string for the first and last index of the specified string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the optional parameter of indexOf.

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();
for (int idx = haystack.indexOf(needle);
     idx != -1;
     idx = haystack.indexOf(needle, idx + 1)) {
  indexes.add(idx);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`indexOf(String str, int fromIndex))`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-int-) in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Use Regex it is better

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String value1= "12345 abc 123 def 123";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("123");
        Matcher  matcher = pattern.matcher(value1);

        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find()){
            count++;
}

        System.out.println(count);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Regex searches are for regular expressions, not literal strings. Escape the input or expect problems with "regexy" needles

Comment: Also in case of `12121` haystack and `121` needle, regex will return only 1 match, while there are 2 overlapping matches.

Answer (score 2):

Try Regexes with `Pattern` and `Matcher`.
Then you can get the start indices with `matcher.start()`, the end indices (exclusive) with `matcher.end()`.

```
String value1 = "12345 abc 123 def 123";
String value2 = "123";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(value2);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value1);

while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("Start: " + matcher.start() + " -- End: " + matcher.end());
}
```

This will give you as output:

```
Start: 0 -- End: 3
Start: 10 -- End: 13
Start: 18 -- End: 21
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement this function yourself. You could use something like:

```
package com.example.stringutils;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Util {
/** Return a list of all the indexes of the 'key' string that occur in the 
 * 'arbitrary' string. If there are none an empty list is returned.
 * 
 * @param key
 * @param arbitrary
 * @return
 */
    private static ArrayList<Integer> allIndexesOf(String key, String arbitrary) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if (key == null |  key.length() == 0 | arbitrary == null | arbitrary.length()<key.length()) {
            return result;
        }

        int loc = -1;
        while ((loc = arbitrary.indexOf(key, loc+1)) > -1) {
            result.add(loc);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You may want to see if regular expressions actually perform faster (fewer code lines aren't always faster, just simpler "code").